What is the easiest or shortest way to show $A = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+6)(n+7)} = \frac{223}{5880} $
What is the easiest or shortest way to show
$$ A = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+6)(n+7)} = \frac{223}{5880} $$
?
Now A has many forms
$$A = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+6)(n+7)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + 6n} - \frac{1}{n^2 + 7n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{7(n+7)} + \frac{1}{42 n} -  \frac{1}{6(n+6)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3 + 13 n^2 + 42n} = ...  $$
and it relates to the digamma function.
Some forms are probably easier to work with than others.
I assume some telescoping method is in the top 4 ?
Can we avoid the digamma ?

I assume Claude's answer is the optimal way. If someone else finds a better way plz give an answer.

Making the problem more general, consider the partial sum$$A_p = \sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac{1}{n(n+a)(n+b)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac{1}{n(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{1}{a (a-b) (n+a)}-\frac{1}{b
   (a-b) (n+b)}+\frac{1}{a b n}$$ gives
$$a b (a-b)\,A_p=a \left(-H_{b+p}+H_b+H_p\right)-b \left(-H_{a+p}+H_a+H_p\right)$$
Now, using, for large $q$
$$H_q=\log (q)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 q}-\frac{1}{12 q^2}
+O\left(\frac{1}{q^3}\right)$$ you end with
$$A_p=\frac{a\, H_b-b\, H_a}{a\, b \,(a-b)}-\frac{1}{2 p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$ from which
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{a\, H_b-b\, H_a}{a\, b \,(a-b)}$$
Edit
If $b=a+1$, this simplify
$$\frac{(a+1) H_a-a}{a (a+1)^2}$$

Nice generalization!

yeah very nice ! +1

We have that
$$\frac{1}{42 n}=\frac1{6n}-\frac1{7n}$$
then
$$\frac{1}{n(n+6)(n+7)}= \frac16\left(\frac1n -  \frac{1}{n+6}\right)-\frac17\left(\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+7}\right) $$
then use telescoping.

As noticed by J.G. in the comments we can further simplify the expression by
$$\ldots=\frac1{42}\left(\frac7n -  \frac{7}{n+6}\right)-\frac1{42}\left(\frac6n-\frac{6}{n+7}\right) =\frac1{42}\left(\frac1n-\frac{1}{n+7}\right)-\frac7{42}\left(\frac1{n+6}-\frac{1}{n+7}\right)$$
which reduces to $\frac{H_7-1}{42}$.

Could you be  more specific ?

@mick This is the easiest way! What about $\sum \frac 1n -\frac 1{n+1}=1-\frac12+\frac12-\frac13+\ldots$? here is similar but more terms survive.

@mick Write down the first 7 terms for $\frac1n -  \frac{1}{n+6}$ and you see that all terms after a while cancel out.

AH i see you do telescoping on both parts.

Yes it seems the way in this case!

Yeah fast. But maybe not the fastest

We have infinite terms, so this one doesn't look so bad! ;)

yeah but still need to add 13 fractions or so.

Well $13/\infty =0$ but maybe some one else will find out some faster way!

OP’s method seems quite fast, regarding the fraction $\dfrac {223}{5880}$.

@mick In terms of harmonic numbers the calculation is$$\frac{H_6}{6}-\frac{H_7}{7}=\frac{H_7-1}{42},$$so you don't need $13$ terms.

@J.G. Right ! nice
